# >= not working correctly

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

In this line of code:

```
sql = "Select CustomerNumber,Surname,Villa,
         Village,Suburb,BookedinDate,BookedInOrder 
         FROM Customers WHERE 
         (BookedInDate >= @StartPeriod And BookedInDate <= @EndPeriod )"
```

where

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartPeriod", StartPeriod)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndPeriod", EndPeriod)
```

and

```
StartPeriod = "01-09-2017"
EndPeriod = "01-15-2017"
```

The datatable contains a record with a BookedInDAte value of "01-09-2017" but is not being picked up in the above Sqlite string.

Any help would be appreciated
Brad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the [usual problem with AddWithValue](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). You pass to it some strings and expect the database engine to convert them to datetime values.
This is doomed from the start. AddWithValue builds a parameter whose datatype is the same of the value passed and of course a string parameter is not valid to be used in a search on a DateTime column.

You should use

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@StartPeriod", DbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Parse(StartPeriod)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@EndPeriod", DbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Parse(EndPeriod)
```

Of course, this works correctly only if your table columns are of type DateTime. If they are instead just strings then we have a completely different problem. You shouldn't store datetime values in a string column. You use the correct datatype otherwise you will never be able to write correct queries against these columns.

Comment: Thanks Steve  I tried these changed but still not working.  My data type was DATE not DATETIME so changed that in SQLite, but it still won't find that record.Variables StartPeriod and EndPeriod are also date variables.

Comment: I am sorry, but cannot reproduce the problem. I have tried with an SQLite database and all works as expected with Date or DateTime columns. So it should be something different, What version of SQLite are you using? Did you debug your code to be sure about the values of the two variables?

Comment: What I can't understand is that records for every other day of the week appear and are selected , it is only the one record for Monday which is the >= search criteria.  I will have to go back and check other areas of the code that may be influencing the result.  Thank you for your help Steve.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. Someone care to explain?

Comment: You probably got downvoted because data types in SQLite don't work they way do in other databases. You should store and work with dates as [ISO-8601 formatted strings](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#date_and_time_datatype) in SQLite.

Comment: Still I have tested this code with an SQLite Version3 install on my PC and the ADO.NET Provider works as expected with a Date or DateTime field created ex-novo in a new database used just for test.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* do this, by piecing together a datetime string of the proper format:

```
StartPeriod = "20170109"
EndPeriod = "20170115"
sql = @"Select CustomerNumber, Surname, Villa, Village, Suburb, BookedinDate,
               BookedInOrder 
        FROM Customer
        WHERE SUBSTR(BookedInDate,7) || SUBSTR(BookedInDate,4,2) ||
              SUBSTR(BookedInDate,1,2) BETWEEN @StartPeriod AND @EndPeriod"
```

But it would be preferable for your to store your date information in a proper format, i.e. `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Comment: Thanks for the idea Tim,  The variable are declared as date and the fields in the datatable are also Date.  As Steve mentioned I didn't want to use strings as it creates even more trouble.

Comment: @Brad There is no date type in SQLite.  You are trying to compare strings which have a non usable format.  My answer should get around this problem.